# Can't Save Products in Admin after editing

Tags: product, configurable-product, admin-panel, magento-2.1

We have a default Magento 2.1 store setup (Nexcess)

We uploaded our products via Dataflow *(I did create a product manually and I am able to edit the simple products)*

**EDIT: It appears it is only for configurable products**

When I go back to edit a product the "gifs" spins but no confirmation of a save.

This applies to all parts of the product section.

I have tried the following:

```
composer update
```

and

```
rm -r www/pub/static/_requirejs/
rm -r www/pub/static/adminhtml/
rm -r www/pub/static/frontend/
rm -f www/pub/static/deployed_version.txt
rm -r www/var/page_cache/
rm -r www/var/view_preprocessed/
rm -rf www/var/di www/var/view_preprocessed/ www/var/tmp/ www/var/cache/ www/var/composer_home/ www/var/generation/ www/var/report/ www/var/page_cache/ www/var/resource_config.json www/var/.cachestates.json www/var/.regenerate
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

That didn't help so I un-tared the 2.1 tarball and re rsync'd it to the project.

I have cleared cache, re-indexed.

No customizations, Fresh Magento 2 install.

We did find this: Do I need to re-compile? I just did that! (I did update permissions)

[image]

Comment: i had issue with the import because was creating duplicates on cataloginventory_stock_item, check if you have for same product_id more than one row

Comment: No such luck. No duplicates in that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web host has specific mod security rules that M2 triggered

> It appears that your site was triggering so mod security rules. I was
>   able to identify the rules and have added the needed exceptions.
>   Please take a moment to test your site to ensure everything is
>   functioning as intended. If you encounter any errors or have any
>   questions please let us know.

All is working now.